# Flutter read from locally stored JSON file

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-listview

I have a local JSON file containing FAQ and I want to load its data in as a list, but I am not able to do that. The code I am using doesn't render anything. Kindly help
This is the stateful widget where I call my json file and want to render it. What I want is that as soon as the stateful widget is triggered, the readJson function is also triggered to store the data in a variable called _items.

```
class FAQScreen extends StatefulWidget {
 FAQScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 State<FAQScreen> createState() => _FAQScreenState();
}

class _FAQScreenState extends State<FAQScreen> {
  var _items = [];

  void initState() {
    readJson().then((value) => print("async done"));
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: IconButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_outlined),
        ),
        title: const Text('FAQ'),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 17, 82, 156),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        children: _items.map((itr) => faqTile(itr['title'])).toList(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

Future<void> readJson() async {
  final String response =
      await rootBundle.loadString('assets/FAQScreens/FAQlist.json');
  final data = await json.decode(response);
  setState(() {
    _items = data;
  });
}
}
```

Below is the definition of faqTile:

```
Widget faqTile(String str) {
  return InkWell(
   onTap: () {},
   child: Container(
     padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
     child: Container(
       child: ListTile(
       onTap: () {},
       contentPadding:
          const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0, right: 0.0, top: 5, bottom:5),
      title: Text(
        str,
        style: const TextStyle(
          fontSize: 16,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
        ),
      ),
      trailing: const Icon(
        Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
        size: 18,
        color: Color(0xff303030),
      ),
    ),
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      border: Border(
        bottom: BorderSide(
          width: 2.0,
          color: Color(0xffcfd8dc),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
);
}
```

Comment: Which directory did your `FAQlist.json` located in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I would think your code should work, using the async function inside your `initState` could cause trouble, if it completes before the call to `super` is complete.

First of all, have you added the JSON file as an asset to your `pubspec.yaml`?
https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/assets-and-images

Secondly, I would, to prevent the async issue from occuring, use a `FutureBuilder` in your Widget (you could then even make it stateless).

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return FutureBuilder<Map<String, dynamic>>(
    future: readJson(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot) {
      Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data ?? {};
      
      return MyAwesomeViewWithJsonData(data: data);
    }
  );
}
```